Transpose rows to column with cell color
I used the below code to transpose data from multiple rows (sheet5) to single column(sheet6). It does the job seamlessly and copy all cell values. But it does not copy the cell color along with values. Any help will be appreciated.
Sub Snake()
  Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long, j As Long
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
  K = 1
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet5")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet6")
  N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To N
   For j = 1 To Columns.Count
     If sh1.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
        sh2.Cells(K, 1).Value = sh1.Cells(i, j).Value
        K = K + 1
     Else
        Exit For
     End If
  Next j
Next i
End Sub


You are literally telling your code to copy .VALUE from one cell to another.  I think you can figure it out by yourself.

I am not that good at writing vba, but can understant it. I used this code from this site. I appreciate some help.

Use
sh1.Cells(i, j).Copy sh2.Cells(K, 1)
instead of
sh2.Cells(K, 1).Value = sh1.Cells(i, j).Value

Using Copy, as suggested above, it will do what you need and even more (copying all the cell format), but for large ranges it will take much more time. If you want to not involve clipboard you can set each property from the copied cell to the target one. Something as sh2.Cells(K, 1).Interior.color = sh1.Cells(i, j).Interior.color,  sh2.Cells(K, 1).Font.color = sh1.Cells(i, j).Font.color`. You can also copy the font type, size etc. depending of your real needs... This will take longer, too.

Wonderful. It is working well and I learnt something today. Thank you FaneDuru and Michal.

Looks like you are trying to create your own =TRANSPOSE() function. Why don't you simply use that? (And in case you don't have it, there's a "Paste Special", "Transpose", what about that?)

I think in your case the simplest way is to use Value(11) instead of simply Value.
The corrected line is:
sh2.Cells(K, 1).Value(11) = sh1.Cells(i, j).Value(11)

Value(11) copies all static formatting and also formulas without references (no conditional formatting, no validation).
